# retrieving most significant 32-bits of a signed long long in c

Tags: c, bit

For some reason the upper 32-bits are lost when referencing bits with a pointer

Machine is little-endian.

```
s64 num = 0x12345678ABCDEF99;
printf("%x%x", *(int* )((&num) + sizeof(int) ) ,*(int* )(&num));
//i used *(int* )(&num)to show that it works only with the first 32 bits
```

output : `0abcdef99`

Comment: isn't it like `%x` expects `unsigned int`?

Comment: Isn't the *upper* 32 bits lost?

Comment: @Weather Vane yes, upper 32 bits are lost , for reasons i do not know

Comment: Better edit the question then.

Comment: Why not do something sensible, like `printf("%llx", num)`?

Comment: @user33866109 i need to store the bits in an int later in the program, so im testing with printf

Comment: In that case, you should start a new thread and ask the real question, "Given a 64-bit number on a machine with 32-bit `int`, how do I extract the upper 32 bits from the number and store them in the `int`?"

Comment: ... or even show us why, when you have `s64`, you can't deal with that later. Is this an X-Y question? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
((&num) + sizeof(int))
```

This does not move `&num` pointer to 4 bytes (assuming `sizeof (int)` being 4), but to 4 `int`, i. e., 16 bytes. This does:

```
((unsigned char *) &num + sizeof (int))
```

Note it is also undefined behavior when you dereference the object as it violates C aliasing rules. As it was also mentioned in the comments, `%x` requires an `unsigned int` but you pass an `int` arguments.

Answer (score -1):

When adding `1` to a pointer of type `T` the address is advanced by `sizeof(T)` and not by `1`.

I believe this would work (if you are compiling it for 64bit):

```
printf("%x%x", *(int* )((u64)(&num) + sizeof(int) ) ,*(int* )(&num));
```

But safer would be:

```
printf("%x%x", (int)((u64)num >> 32) ,(int)num);
```

**EDIT:**

I don't think that this is the case but in case you didn't know, `printf` supports also 64 bit values in the following format:

```
printf("%llx", num);
```

Comment: i do know, but i need those bits stored in an int for some later use in my program, so I am testing with printf to make sure im using the right code

Comment: If you want to split a signed 64-bit int for later use, you'll be in trouble unless you use unsigned. Do you really need signed?

Comment: i didn't really specify the question but my original concern was how i was unable to reference those bits with a pointer, 
EDIT: the 64-bit value is hardcoded right now, but it will later be a result of signed multiplication

Comment: @hec you either have to cast the address to `char*` or to big enough integer to hold the pointer value and then add the offset in **bytes** like you did in the question.

Comment: Right shifting a negative integer is _implementation defined_. And wiered pointer-arithmetic is never a good idea.

Comment: @Olaf You are correct about shifting negative integers. Fixed. *wiered pointer-arithmetic* is indeed never a good idea but sometimes one has no other choice.

Comment: @AlexLop.: (I meant weird, of course) If  it violates strict aliasing rules, it actually is **never** a good idea..

Comment: So cast the negative integer to unsigned.  That’s defined behavior.

Comment: Excuse me; on reading the edit, the question was asking how to do pointer arithmetic correctly, not how to extract only the 32 most-significant bits.  I was answering the wrong question.  Pardon.